# MySQL: finding the max number of bids on items only if they've been selected by specified buyer

Tags: mysql, database

The MySQL database schema is:

> Bids(id, buyer, amount)

The question is:
For each item that buyerNum 'abc' has bid on, list the id, number of different bids made on it (by all users not just 'abc') and the highest value bid.

What I've tried is

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*), MAX(amount)
FROM Bids
WHERE buyer = "abc"
GROUP BY id
```

But the count only counts for the number of times 'abc' has put in a bid for that item's id. I was attempting some kind of join to make the count surpass the "buyer = "abc"" condition, but I'm very new to MySQL so I'm struggling. Help please!

Comment: do you want to count all buyer attempt(total_attempt) for any id?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.id,
       a.total,
       MAX(b.amount) 
  FROM Bids b
  LEFT JOIN (select count(*) as total,id from Bids GROUP BY id) a 
    on b.id = a.id
 WHERE buyer = "abc" 
 GROUP 
    BY b.id
```

Hopefully it will be working fine.